# Roslyn recommends incorrect symbols for a method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Just came across that in VS2015 community(as well as VS2017 RC)

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Bar() { }

    public static void Foo(int n)
    {
        Bar.
    }
}
```

After `Bar.` the following auto-completions are recommended.

- (parameter) int n
- MemberwiseClone
- Equals
- GetHashCode
- GetType
- ToString

I think the latter 4 methods (from `object`) makes sense because I can add a variable/field named `Bar` later, but I don't see `(parameter) int n` and `MemberwiseClone` make any sense. By the way, [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) has the correct behavior here. To make sure it's not a IDE specific issue, I try to get completions from Roslyn via

```
namespace Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Recommendations
{
    public static class Recommender
    {
        public static Task<IEnumerable<ISymbol>> GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPositionAsync(
            SemanticModel semanticModel, 
            int position, 
            Workspace workspace, 
            OptionSet options = null, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    }
}
```

**My first attempt**

```
        var code = @"
namespace IntellisenseTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Bar() { }

        public static void Foo(int n)
        {
            Bar.         
        }
    }
}";
        var intellisense = "Bar.";
        var sourceText = SourceText.From(code);
        var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceText);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("IntellisenseTest").AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
        var position = code.IndexOf(intellisense) + intellisense.Length + 1;
        var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
        var symbols = await Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPositionAsync(
            semanticModel,
            position,
            workspace);

        //print symbols
```

But I only get one recommended completion named `n`.

Then I create a real solution/project with the `string code` above on my hard drive.

**Second attempt**

```
var solutionPath = @"C:\workspace\IntellisenseTest\IntellisenseTest.sln";
var fileName = "Class1.cs";
var intellisense = "Bar.";

var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
var project = solution.Projects.First();
var document = project.Documents.Single(d => d.Name == fileName);
var text = await document.GetTextAsync();
var position = text.ToString().IndexOf(intellisense) + intellisense.Length + 1;
var syntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

var symbols = await Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPositionAsync(
    semanticModel, 
    position, 
    workspace);

//print symbols I got
n
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
GetType
MemberwiseClone
```

**Q1: What's the difference between the two implementations above? IMO I should get the same result.**

**Q2: Why Roslyn recommends these completions? IMO `n` and `MemberwiseClone` don't make any sense.**

Comment: because you don't have metadata references for `System.Object` etc in you custom compilation

Comment: @m0sa: probably right, post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**A2**: All of the suggested completions are [`System.Object` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object_methods.aspx), from which all types in C# derive from.

**A1**: You don't have a reference to the assembly that defines `System.Object` in your manually constructed msbuild workspace. The one with the .sln probably has it.

In your first attempt, add it to the project

```
project = project.AddMetadataReference(
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Object).Assembly.Location));
```

or the compilation

```
compilation = compilation.AddReferences(
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Object).Assembly.Location));
```

and you should get identical results.